# Apache 2.2 Server Issue

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

So I've been running Apache 2.2 on Windows for a few years. The website is really only up and running a few months out of the year; the rest of the time it gets no traffic and is generally ignored.

As I went ramp it up this year, I've found that I get a 404 error whenever I attempt to access the site outside the network. What's more, the 404 error isn't a standard Apache error page, but rather has a mini httpd link at the bottom.

I'm at a loss for what do. Everything runs fine when I use local host on that machine. I've verified that my IP address hasn't changed by googling "what's my ip". I've verified that port 80 is set to forward to the correct box via my router. I'm concerned that I may have been hacked, with someone setting up the mini httpd server, or else I did it inadvertently.

Can anyone offer any guidance/next steps? Thank you for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: "on Windows 2000 for a few years".  More than "a few", I'd guess...

Comment: Then you'd guess wrong. Just started trying to teach myself a few years ago using an old desktop I had lying around. Do you have anything constructive to add?

Comment: One note, Jake - if you're trying to teach yourself how to use an apache web server, ditch the Windows 2000 OS and install a modern Linux distribution. Apache was designed to run on unix-like system, not windows, and you'll benefit from actually learning a platform that is relevant in today's market.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, so on a whim I cleared the forwarding in the router, then reconfigured...and voila it worked. No idea how, but apparently somehow became corrupted in the router settings. Hope this helps someone else in my shoes.